# How can I install a Pantum 2502W laser printer on Ubuntu

Tags: printing

Attempting to add with the printer application doesn't list the manufacturer.

`lsusb` output before plugging in is:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 10d5:5a08 Uni Class Technology Co., Ltd
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

`lsusb` output after plugging in is:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 232b:2820
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 10d5:5a08 Uni Class Technology Co., Ltd
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

I searched the web for 232b:2820 to see if it was a re-brand or compatible with a better supported brand but to no avail.

Comment: Can you provide any more info please? This doesn't look like it's enough to go after.

Comment: @ElderGeek: Define "Not appropriate"  Is it rude to you?  ;-)  Flesh it out a bit!  You're showing up in the "Low quality question" queue

Comment: @Fabby :-) Will add lsusb info ASAP

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the driver "Pantum P2200-P2500 Series Linux Driver  ZIP     2014-5-20   1.10" on the manufacturers page [here](http://global.pantum.com/global/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=supportdetails&pid=33&Itemid=108)

Downloaded and extracted the contents to my desktop with Archive manager (aka file-roller)

While the archive includes an installation script it fails even after adjusting permissions to make it executable so we navigate to the Resources folder, select the appropriate deb file (in my case i386)

[image: driver]

and install it with Software Center acknowledging the warning and continuing to install.

[image: SoftCent]

Now open the printers application and choose Add. You should see an option like this: [image: addingpantum]

Choose Forward, edit details if necessary, then click print test page

[image: finishing]

Congratulations! You've just installed the P2502W laser printer under Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: And 2 upvotes (and a free edit of your question). Next time, highlight the output and press [Ctrl][K].

Comment: This also works on 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

A slight addition in 16.04 if you try to install the driver though software manager nothing happens, I opened a terminal and entered

```
sudo dpkg -i Pantum-P2500-Series-2.6.x86_64.deb
```

that fixed it :)

Comment: 16.04's default Ubuntu software (3.20.1) is a bit flaky. Fortunately  The tried and true Ubuntu Software Center (15.12) is still available for 16.04